# Problem with Displaying JLabels

Tags: java, forms, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

Hi am new to java and have been trying to create a form for a college project.
I am in early development stages and i have my text fields working but my label is not visable.
Also my text areas are far to large stretching the whole of my Jframe.
Here is my currant Code
This Jframe opens automaticly when the User Loggs in the the previous class named (java.java.) This class is called (AddProperty.java)

```
package Main;

/**
 *
 * @author Graeme
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class AddProperty
{

    public void gui()
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AddPropertyFrame");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        JLabel HouseNumber = new JLabel();
        panel.add(HouseNumber);
        JTextField HouseNumber1 = new JTextField();
        panel.add(HouseNumber1);

        JLabel HousePrice = new JLabel();
        panel.add(HousePrice);
        JTextField HousePrice1 = new JTextField();
        panel.add(HousePrice1);

        JLabel HouseType = new JLabel();
        panel.add(HouseType);
        JTextField HouseType1 = new JTextField();
        panel.add(HouseType1);

        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        panel.add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(new Action());
    }

    static class Action implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {

            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Submitted");
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.setSize(200,200);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("You Have Submitted a New Property");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame2.add(panel);
            panel.add(label);


        }

    }

}
```

Thanks, any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your JLabels are not being shown is because it is given no value to show.

try adding a value when calling its constructor, for example;

```
new JLabel("House Nummber");
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the JLabels are not visible because they don't have something to display in them...

try putting a value for the JLabel when you call its constructor... this is just my guess though...

```
new JLabel("House Nummber");
```

Comment: Yeah thanks i missed that for some reason i thought it was going to fill it in from the label name i assigned. Thats solved my missing lables but for some reason my textfields are still the size of the screen virticaly insted of being a box like you would expect to see when entering infomation. Thanks alot!

Comment: that's what BoxLayout does. When you use XAXIS, components are laid out left to right, and fill the whole screen in the vertical direction. YOu should be using frame.pack() vs. frame.setSize(200,200); and that will solve the problem when the dialog is shown. However if someone resizes, then you will still get the problem you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments in the code.

### Altered AddProperty.java

```
/**
 *
 * @author Graeme
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class AddProperty
{

    public void gui()
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AddPropertyFrame");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // having to set sizes of components is rare, and often a sign    
        // of problems with layouts.
        //frame.setSize(800,600);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20,20));
        // make it big like the original
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(100,20,100,20));
        frame.add(panel);
        //panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        JLabel HouseNumber = new JLabel("A");
        panel.add(HouseNumber);
        JTextField HouseNumber1 = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(HouseNumber1);

        JLabel HousePrice = new JLabel("B");
        panel.add(HousePrice);
        JTextField HousePrice1 = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(HousePrice1);

        JLabel HouseType = new JLabel("C");
        panel.add(HouseType);
        JTextField HouseType1 = new JTextField(5);
        panel.add(HouseType1);

        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        panel.add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(new Action());

        // tell the GUI to assume its natural (minimum) size.
        frame.pack();
    }

    static class Action implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            // this should probably be a modal JDialog or JOptionPane.
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Submitted");
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.setSize(200,200);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("You Have Submitted a New Property");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame2.add(panel);
            panel.add(label);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AddProperty addProperty = new AddProperty();
                addProperty.gui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Screen shot

[image]